# Java detecting strings

Tags: java, string, if-statement, system.in

I'm trying to make a program in which if you type in "open" to the java console it ends.

When I type in open, the if statement below doesn't run.

```
            if(input=="open") {
                System.out.println("You escaped!!");
                break;
            }
```

I've also tried .equals and it still doesn't work

```
    if(input.equals("open")) {
        System.out.println("You escaped!!");
        break;
    }
```

However when I print out input as shown below, the input is open.  This makes no sense because if the input was open, then the if statement above should have run.

```
            else{
                //otherwise check what was written
                System.out.println(input);
            }
```

Here is my full code:

```
class Password {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        //holds letters put in
        char letter;

        //holds full line of input
        String input;


        for(;;){
            input="";

            //makes the input equal what was inputed on the line
            for(;;){
                //gets next char
                letter=(char) System.in.read(); //get a char
                //if the line hasn't ended then add that char to input
                if(letter!='\n'){
                    input+=String.valueOf(letter);
                }else{
                    //other wise line has ended so input is finished
                    break;
                }
            }
            //if open was typed in then end the program
            if(input.equals("open")) {
                System.out.println("You escaped!!");
                break;
            }else{
                //otherwise check the input
                System.out.println(input);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: You probably have invisible whitespace following the character `open`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how could I see and remove that?

Comment: Try the `String#trim()` method. You can also check the length of the `String` to make sure.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks it worked! Any idea of what caused the whitespace?

Comment: Read the javadoc for `InputStream#read()` which you're using in `System.in.read()`. When you press enter to submit input, that's also considered a byte (or more) read. Consider using a `Scanner`.